# Scala how to remove object in Map

Tags: json, scala

I have object:
List(Map(uniqueValue -> As Expected, count -> 5851), **Map(uniqueValue -> , count -> 1341)**, Map(uniqueValue -> Worse than Expected, count -> 430), Map(uniqueValue -> Better than Expected, count -> 4))

I want to remove object whose uniqueValue is empty, like *Map(uniqueValue -> , count -> 1341)

Comment: What is the type of your data? How can a key be empty? Maybe it is null? Or an empty string? What have you tried? - BTW, if the maps always have two keys with the same name, why not using a **case class** instead?

Comment: And this has nothing to do with JSONs, at least in the scope of the question.

Comment: @ Mohd. Mahtab Alam added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

collect all values in the map and filter the null or empty ones as required.

```
object Test extends App {
    
      val mapList = List(
        Map("uniqueValue" -> "As Expected", "count" -> 5851),
        Map("uniqueValue" -> null, "count" -> 1341),
        Map("uniqueValue" -> "Worse than Expected", "count" -> 430),
        Map("uniqueValue" -> "Better than Expected", "count" -> 4)
      )
    
      val filteredMap = mapList.filter(!_.values.toSet.contains(null))
    
      println(filteredMap)
    
    }
```

result

```
List(Map(uniqueValue -> As Expected, count -> 5851), Map(uniqueValue -> Worse than Expected, count -> 430), Map(uniqueValue -> Better than Expected, count -> 4))
```